# PHP - How to merge not-specified number of arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, json, array-merge

Is it possible to merge non-specified number of array elements in PHP?

I received data through JSON string (n elements), then I used them to do n loops - each loop saves the result to a different array cell (`$result[1], $result[2], $result[3], ... ,$result[n]`). I would like to merge the results into a single array (I have to send single array through JSON). Everything works if I write manually `array_merge ($result[1], $result[2], $result[3])`, but I never know how many variables I will receive.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `call_user_func_array('array_merge', $result);`

Comment: Why do you save the result in different arrays if you can just throw them in the same array in the first place?

Comment: Hm this is a bit complicated ;) In main loop I execute 5 different SQL statements and save results into arrays: $result1, $result2, $result3, $result4, $result5. So after all n loops I got $result1[0], $result1[1], $result1[n], then $result2[0], $result2[1] etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$yourListOfArrays = [$result[1], $result[2], ...];

call_user_func_array('array_merge',$yourListOfArrays);
```

Comment: I wonder who down-voted this answer. Can you comment what's the issue?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but how is that different?  You still need to know how many arrays.

Comment: No you dont. You can loop all your arrays into the `$yourListOfArrays`. Then you don't need to know them upfront. So for the OP it would probably just be `$result`. But it can not if the array contains other stuff.

Comment: If i could specifed $yourListOfArrays then i would be able to use simple array_merge($result[1], $result[2], ...) :)

Rocket Hazmat's answer solved my problem.

Comment: My answer is exactly, 1:1, the same as his. I'm just showing the added array-buildup in case your `$result` object would contain more than just arrays. You might for example wanted to shift those non-array keys out of it. That's the reason. Besides that my answer is no different.

Comment: @belialek `$yourListOfArrays` is your `$result`. Allendar wasn't straight forward with that fact.

Comment: @Allendar Ooohh, of course it is! :)My bad, it's after midnight here :) Thank you so much for your help, i'm still learning